# Internet connection only works for a few hours

Tags: networking, internet, suspend, shutdown

I have Ubuntu 16.04, and at random points in time, my internet connection just stops working. It is connected but I have no internet access. Here's what I've tried so far :

- Toggle Wifi off and on again using the keyboard button. // Didn't work, either connects to my wifi but still no internet access or looks like it's connecting forever
- Log off and on. // Didn't work
- Suspend and back. // Didn't work
- Reboot. // Shows wifi as device not ready. Suspend and back seems to fix the problem.
- Shutdown and power up again. //Seems to fix the problem until connection just stops working after an hour or two.

So the two things that fix the problem are Reboot+Suspend or Shutdown. But these are not viable solutions as this happens every two hours or so.

PS: If Ubuntu didn't power down and up so fast I would've lost my mind a long time ago.

Comment: Does it help to do: `sudo service network-manager restart` ?

Comment: I tried that, doesn't work